# How can I invert a Google Document?

Tags: android, xml

How can I start my document from the last page? I have a document over 100 pages, and I want to invert it.I want to star it from the end. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post the attempted code?

Comment: This question is just vague. Which API are you using to read the document?

Comment: Without which API and what kind of document it's impossible to solve your problem

Comment: Its a google document